# Request Throttled : Azure App Configuration

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-configuration

So I am testing Azure App Configuration. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/quickstart-dotnet-core-app

I am trying free plan for this, which has 1000 requests limit. 
My App Config store would have somewhere around 50 configs stored in it, which I retrieved in my `startup.cs` file, which, I guess is loaded only once when I start my Azure Functions.

[image]

But to my surprise, after testing it for a couple of times, it's returning 429 - Request throttled. 
So my question is, how Azure counts request to App Config? Is it per store or per config key-value?

Answer (score 1):

Requests to App Configuration is counted per store. Given you have 50 config settings, they should be all retrieved with just one request. You may like to check the "total request count" graph on the overview page of the Azure portal to learn more of your usage. The link below also has a few suggestions about how to reduce the requests.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/howto-best-practices#reduce-requests-made-to-app-configuration